# Doubt about rviz and change of Object types

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i've this launch to run rviz:

```
<node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" respawn="false" output="log">
    <param name="video_device" type="string" value="/dev/video1"/>
    <param name="camera_frame_id" type="string" value="usb_cam"/>
    <param name="io_method" type="string" value="mmap"/>
    <param name="image_width" type="int" value="640"/>
    <param name="image_height" type="int" value="480"/>
    <param name="pixel_format" type="string" value="yuyv"/>
    <rosparam param="D">[0.025751483065329935, -0.10530741936574876,-0.0024821434601277623, -0.0031632353637182972, 0.0000]</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="K">[558.70655574536931, 0.0, 316.68428342491319, 0.0, 553.44501004322387, 238.23867473419315, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="R">[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]</rosparam>
    <rosparam param="P">[558.70655574536931, 0.0, 316.68428342491319, 0.0, 0.0, 553.44501004322387, 238.23867473419315, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]</rosparam>
</node>

<node name="ar_pose" pkg="ar_pose" type="ar_single" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <param name="marker_pattern" type="string" value="$(find ar_pose)/data/patt.hiro"/>
    <param name="marker_width" type="double" value="80.0"/>
    <param name="marker_center_x" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="marker_center_y" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="threshold" type="int" value="100"/>
    <param name="use_history" type="bool" value="true"/>
```

With this launch, i run rviz with 4 displays which are default in live_single.vcg.

Background\ ColorR=0
Background\ ColorG=0
Background\ ColorB=0
Fixed\ Frame=/world
Target\ Frame=
Camera.Alpha=0.5
Camera.Enabled=1
Camera.Image\ Topic=/usb_cam/image_raw
Grid.Alpha=0.5
Grid.Cell\ Size=1
Grid.ColorR=0.654902
Grid.ColorG=0
Grid.ColorB=0
Grid.Enabled=1
Grid.Line\ Style=0
Grid.Line\ Width=0.03
Grid.Normal\ Cell\ Count=0
Grid.OffsetX=0
Grid.OffsetY=0
Grid.OffsetZ=0
Grid.Plane=0
Grid.Plane\ Cell\ Count=10
Grid.Reference\ Frame=
Markers.Enabled=1
Markers.Marker\ Topic=visualization_marker
Markers.basic_shapes=1
TF.All\ Enabled=1
TF.Enabled=1
TF.Show\ Arrows=1
TF.Show\ Axes=1
TF.Show\ Names=1
TF.Update\ Rate=0
Tool\ 2D\ Nav\ GoalTopic=goal
Tool\ 2D\ Pose\ EstimateTopic=initialpose
Camera\ Type=rviz::OrbitViewController
Camera\ Config=1.07693 0.461088 5.5806 0 0 0
Property\ Grid\ State=selection=Target Frame;expanded=.Global Options,TF./ar_marker/ar_marker,TF./usb_cam/usb_cam,TF./ar_markerTree/ar_marker,TF./usb_camTree/usb_cam,Markers.Enabled.Markers.StatusTopStatus,Markers.Enabled.Markers.Namespaces;scrollpos=0,0;splitterpos=133,266;ispageselected=1
[Display0]
Name=TF
Package=rviz
ClassName=rviz::TFDisplay
[Display1]
Name=Markers
Package=rviz
ClassName=rviz::MarkerDisplay
[Display2]
Name=Camera
Package=rviz
ClassName=rviz::CameraDisplay
[Display3]
Name=Grid
Package=rviz
ClassName=rviz::GridDisplay
[TF.]
ar_markerEnabled=1
usb_camEnabled=1

However, it runs represented by arrows (1.3.1 of the next url)

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker

I wish run as a CUBE (1). I suppose that i have to change in:

visualization_marker (visualization_msgs/Marker)

marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::ARROW; by marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::CUBE;

But i don't know where is this topic to change it.

In a few words, i wish representate my problem as a cube or other figure.

Another question. Would it possible to representate while the figure i would wish?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32115/doubt-about-rviz-and-change-of-object-types/) by [alonsosjumper](https://answers.ros.org/users/2135/alonsosjumper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the API doc
[here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/Marker.html)
and wiki [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines)

Which comment says

```
#Only used if the type specified has some use for them (eg. POINTS, LINE_STRIP, ...)
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
#Only used if the type specified has some use for them (eg. POINTS, LINE_STRIP, ...)
#number of colors must either be 0 or equal to the number of points
#NOTE: alpha is not yet used
std_msgs/ColorRGBA[] colors
```

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0